# Error BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

Tags: vb.net

I have searching for a fix and made every change I can think of but only create more errors. I am trying to make check boxes that will save the users username and/or password when the box is checked. Any help would be much appreciated. I do have the setting added for password and username.

```
Private Sub Launcher_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    TextBox.Text = My.Settings.Username
    PasswordBox.Password = My.Settings.Password
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    My.Settings.Username = TextBox.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
    My.Settings.Reload()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox_Checked_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    My.Settings.Password = PasswordBox.Password
    My.Settings.Save()
    My.Settings.Reload()
End Sub
```

Comment: Every time you save a password in plain-text, someone strangles a kitten. This is one of those things that's too important to even let it slide for practice code.

Comment: Also, give the textbox a different name than "TextBox". It matches the type name, and therefore confuses the compiler.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Re Joel's comment, similarly for PasswordBox.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, What triggers the `CheckBox_Checked()` Subs ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are missing the Handle of the Checkbox.

```
Class MainWindow
        Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
            txtUserName.Text = My.Settings.Username
            pwbPassword.Password = My.Settings.Password
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub checkBoxSaveCredentials_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles checkBoxSaveCredentials.Checked
            My.Settings.username = txtUserName.Text
            My.Settings.password = pwbPassword.Password 'Comment: understand that you are using a WPF textbox that has the property password.
            My.Settings.Save()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

You are missing this part: **Handles checkBoxSaveCredentials.Checked**

On the other hand, you should never save the password in cleartext. If using the credentials locally: Please hash the password and then save the hash. Compare the password hash every time to give access. OR if using the credential to access an external site or app then encrypt it (but now you need to know how to protect the encryption key!) (this password saving problem cannot be discussed in a few lines).

Also, in your code use conventions for the names of the objects and variables. For example, txtUserName, txtPassword, checkBoxSaveCredentials in this case.

Edited to show code using WPF. I re-created your project and it all worked.

Comment: In this context, the password might be saved for submission to an external site, in which case hashing it won't work.

Comment: @Craig  that is true, but I do not know that. He seems to be in the early stage of learning how to code. Anyway, I have edited the answer to encrypt in case the credentials are to be used externally.

Comment: This appears to be a WPF application (RoutedEventArgs is a clue) so the Handles clause is not used. Events in WPF are wired a bit differently.

Comment: @Mary Yes it does use handles. I just re-created his project using a WPF project as he did and handles are indeed used.

Comment: @Mary, I edited my answer to sow actual WPF code. I did build a project and it all worked.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers OP's problem.  I think the problem is simple: They named their instance of `TextBox` the same as the class, so the call to `TextBox.Text` tries to find a shared member on the class, and fails.  Ditto for PasswordBox.

Comment: @SeanSkelly I just tested it using the username TextBox named TextBox and it worked. My answer stand as it is. He is missing the handles.

Comment: @Mary You can do event wiring with `Handles`, in which case the IDE will identify it as associated with the control object, or you can do it by specifying the handler in the xaml, in which case the generated code will wire up the event *but* the IDE won't identify the connection to the control object.

Comment: @Craig I find in order to use the handles clause, I need to specify the event in the properties window in the designer. Since the OP did share the XAML for the CheckBox I don't see how the addition of a Handles clause would necessarily solve his problem. I would think it would be better to do this the with the xaml since I don't think handles is available in C# and it would be better to learn a method that will work in both languages.

Comment: In my experience, I haven't needed to do anything in the properties window.  The one thing you do need to do is ensure that the object has a language-visible name, I don't think they necessarily do (but I generally do all my xaml by hand and only use the designer for some spot checks on layout).  As for C# compatibility; I guess it depends on your circumstances.  I'd prefer not to use VB as if it were C#.  If I need to cater to C#, then I work in C#.

Comment: @Mary forgot to tag you on my previous comment.

Comment: @Craig Thanks, got it now.